# How to sort a ComboBox.Items collection of KeyValuePair<string,string> by Value?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, combobox

I'm getting a KeyValuePair from a **service** and some of the values are not sorted, as reproduced below.

**How can I resort the KeyValuePair by value so that they display in alphabetical order in the ComboBox:**

```
public NationalityComboBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(null, "Please choose..."));
    Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("111", "American"));
    Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("777", "Zimbabwean"));
    Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("222", "Australian"));
    Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("333", "Belgian"));
    Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("444", "French"));
    Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("555", "German"));
    Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("666", "Georgian"));
    SelectedIndex = 0;

}
```

Comment: How is the service returning the data to you? A dictionary? An array? A list? A load of separate objects?

Comment: sorry: the collection is a System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection of KeyValuePair<string,string> objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are getting them from a service, I assume that they are in a list or a set of some sort?

---

If you are using a list of items, you can user the LINQ Extension Method `.OrderBy()` to sort the list:

```
var myNewList = myOldList.OrderBy(i => i.Value);
```

---

If you are getting the data as a DataTable, you can set the default view of the table like this:

```
myTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Value ASC";
```

Answer (score 3):

When you databind an `ItemsControl` (such as a `ComboBox`, a `ListBox`...), you can manage sort operations using the `ICollectionViewInterface`. Basically, you retrieve the instance using the `CollectionViewSource` class:

```
var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.collections);
```

Then you can add sort using the SortDescription:

```
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pre-sort with a list:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs =
        new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>( /* whatever */ );

pairs.Sort(
    delegate(KeyValuePair<string, string> x, KeyValuePair<string, string> y)
    {
        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(x.Value, y.Value);
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks, this is nice, works on my example, but in the application I ended up using John's OrderBy.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the collection returned from the service implements `IEnumerable<T>`, then you should be able to do something like this:

```
Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(null, "Please choose..."));
foreach (var item in collectionReturnedFromService.OrderBy(i => i.Value))
{
    Items.Add(item);
}
```